# handle multiple values from inputs user in vscode tasks

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

What are the best solutions to receive input from user in `inputs` vscode on `tasks.json` then according chosen option to handle multiple values?

Is there any solution like this bellow?

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "inputs": [
        {
            "id": "selectProject",
            "type": "pickString",
            "description": "Some decription",
            "options": 
            [
                { 
                    "label": "project1", 
                    "value" : {"path":"","name":"","link":"","anyOther":""}  // something like this
                } ,
                { 
                    "label": "project2", 
                    "value" : {"path":"","name":"","link":"","anyOther":""}  // something like this
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "test on projects",
            "type": "process",
            "command": "echo",
            "args": [
                "${input:selectProject.path}", // handle many info from one chosen option
                "${input:selectProject.name}",
                 "${input:selectProject.link}",
                 "${input:selectProject.anyOther}"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

currently options can receive only one value :(

```json
 "options": 
            [
                { "label": "project1", "value" : "value"  } ,
                { "label": "project2", "value" : "value"  }
            ]
```

Comment: where have you found that `pickString` supports `label-value` pairs

Comment: I don't know. I'm just using it. It works for me on label-value. May be any extension I have?

Answer (score 1):

You can use extension [Command Variable](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable) v1.22.0.

The command `extension.commandvariable.pickStringRemember` can remember multiple values for 1 pick.

The syntax of the label-value is a bit different because I did not know `pickString` supported that.

```json
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "Do some project",
      "type": "process",
      "command": "echo",
      "args": [
        "${input:selectProject.path}",
        "${input:selectProject.name}",
        "${input:selectProject.link}",
        "${input:selectProject.anyOther}"
      ],
      "problemMatcher": []
    }
  ],
  "inputs": [
    {
      "id": "selectProject.path",
      "type": "command",
      "command": "extension.commandvariable.pickStringRemember",
      "args": {
        "key": "path",
        "options": [
          ["project1", {"path":"p1","name":"n1","link":"lnk1","anyOther":"any1"}],
          ["project2", {"path":"p2","name":"n2","link":"lnk2","anyOther":"any2"}]
         ],
        "description": "Pick a project"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "selectProject.name",
      "type": "command",
      "command": "extension.commandvariable.rememberPick",
      "args": { "key": "name" }
    },
    {
      "id": "selectProject.link",
      "type": "command",
      "command": "extension.commandvariable.rememberPick",
      "args": { "key": "link" }
    },
    {
      "id": "selectProject.anyOther",
      "type": "command",
      "command": "extension.commandvariable.rememberPick",
      "args": { "key": "anyOther" }
    }
  ]
}
```